# Store key in compact form

Tags: openssl, public-key-encryption, pki

I have generated keys with command below:

```
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
```

According to my understanding key size should be 2048 bits that is 256 bytes.

This brings key in PEM format that takes 1,6kb space. This is too huge for my application. Ihave converted PEM to DER format :

```
openssl rsa -inform PEM -outform DER -in server.key -out server.key.der
```

In der format it takes about 1 Kb. Still too much.

How to get plane key size that is 256 bytes?

Comment: 256 bytes is only the size of the modulus. The other components of the private key take up more space if you use standard formats like PKCS#1 or formats that encapsulate PKCS#1-formatted rsa private keys, like PKCS#8. It's possible to get away with 256 bytes if you use a fixed public exponent like 65537 and a few other assumptions. Since you'd be abandoning the standard formats you'll be on your own for reading in the key and turning into a private object for whatever platform/library you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Elliptic Curve (ECC) keys which are mush smaller:

```
openssl genpkey -out small.pem.p8
```

The size of the PEM key is 119 bytes

You can also output to a raw DER form:

```
openssl genpkey -out small.der.p8 -algorithm ed25519 -outform DER
```

Now it's size is only 48 bytes. And it contains internally it's public key.